# protection of pages in virtual memory

Tags: linux, operating-system

I read in a tutorial that although ***intel segmentation*** is not used in linux,there is the protection or mode information in ***code segment selector*** and ***data segment selector***.And in virtual memory tutorial i read about protection of pages using page table depending on the modes they are running in.

I wanted to know how these two mechanisms are related?

At what stage protection information on pages is added into page table?Does CPU checks Code segment selector and depending on it page table flag is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although **segmentation** is (almost) not used by Linux, because you can't turn it off on x86, **segmentation** is  merely bypassed through a *protected flat memory model*.

Actually **segmentation** is mandatory, and you do have to setup the code and data segment selectors when crafting a kernel, just because those segment selectors setup the current privilege level of execution (the CPL): basically *ring 0* (supervisor mode) or *ring 3* (userland). The selectors (registers CS, DS, ...) host an offset into the GDT. Depending on the descriptor pointed by this offset, the system is running with a given level of privilege, see [Intel manual 3A, chapter 3.2.2](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253668.pdf?bcsi_scan_46DC433717929B81=0&bcsi_scan_filename=253668.pdf) for more information about using segments.

As you can see, with the *protected flat memory model*, there is no direct checks on attributes on access to the memory (neither for code or data). And you guessed it right!  The MMU (I would rather say **paging**) undertakes  to check the access depending on the CPL of the system and the page's U/S attibute.

It is up to the kernel (therefore executing in *ring 0*) to setup the page directory, with relevant pages' attributes.